# How to know the actual version of Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I want to get some books to better work with Azure DevOps that is installed on-premise at work and I want to get the most recent book for the version/edition that is installed.

How can I know what is the version / edition we are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the version number of the actually running instance by going to the following URL (adapt for your own environment):

```
http://<server:port>/<base Azure path without project name>/_home/about
```

For instance, if my project (name P1) url is

```
http://myserver:8080/azure/P1
```

The about page will be

```
http://myserver:8080/azure/_home/about
```